# Run a bash script inside another bash script and pass variables

Tags: bash

I have two bash scripts. The second one is called from the first one. Here's the second one which is named `build_with_docker.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=$1
BUILD_ID=$2

echo "-- build/platform/build_with_docker.sh --"
echo VERSION:$VERSION
echo BUILD_ID:$BUILD_ID
# override params
if [ -z "$VERSION" ]
then
    echo "Failed to pass version :("
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$BUILD_ID" ]
then
    echo "Failed to pass BUILD_ID :("
fi

SOURCEID=$(docker build -q -f - --build-arg semver=$VERSION --build-arg build_id=$BUILD_ID $GOPATH/src/myproject < $DEVOPS/build/platform/Dockerfile.build)
echo $SOURCEID
```

I want to call the above script from the first one. Here's the first one:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=${1:-${VERSION}}
if [ -z "$VERSION" ]
then
    echo "VERSION not defined in shell session, nor passed in as parameter"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$BUILD_ID" ]
then
    BUILD_ID=$(date +%s)
    echo "Setting build id to current date"
fi

# Builds, and outputs image to Docker's local image store
# example "sha256:59d19c43c86865aef8..."
DOCKER_IMAGE_ID=`$DEVOPS/build/platform/build_with_docker.sh ${VERSION} ${BUILD_ID}`
echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_ID
```

When I execute the first script, the second one never gets executed and the `$DOCKER_IMAGE_ID` is empty. If I remove the two arguments `${VERSION}` and `${BUILD_ID}` passed to the second script, then it works.

EDIT: $DEVOPS is a environment variable which is already set

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: For one: quote your variables so they don't get split: `$DEVOPS/build/platform/build_with_docker.sh "${VERSION}" "${BUILD_ID}"`

Comment: @JNevill did that. Still no luck

Comment: What is `$DEVOPS` is that a global? What do you get when you `echo $DEVOPS/build/platform/build_with_docker.sh "${VERSION}" "${BUILD_ID}"` ? Is it pointing to the right script. Does everything look like how when you run it manually.

Comment: @JNevill Just edited the original post. `$DEVOPS` is an env var which is already set. And yes, everything works if I run manually

Comment: What bash version, OS, and OS version?  I can't reproduce the failure with a simple test case of two scripts in the same directory.  That said, try `DOCKER_IMAGE_ID="$("$DEVOPS/build/platform/build_with_docker.sh" "${VERSION}" "${BUILD_ID}")"` (yes, two levels of quoting) to make sure nothing is being split improperly.

Comment: I'm on a mac with the latest OS. Bash version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` . Tried with the two levels of quoting. Still the same problem

Comment: Change the first line of each script to `#!/bin/bash -xv` and run again to get *debug output*.

Comment: @cxw, the outer quoting layer isn't needed, since string-splitting and glob expansion are suppressed on assignments; `DOCKER_IMAGE_ID=$("$DEVOPS"/build/platform/build_with_docker.sh "$VERSION" "$BUILD_ID")` would be just as correct. (You're right, though, that the OP's original code was buggy due to inadequate quoting).

Comment: (that said, the all-caps names for user-defined variables are bad form in and of themselves -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, guaranteeing that names with at least one lowercase character are safe for application use, whereas all-caps names can be meaningful to -- and thus change behavior of -- POSIX-defined tools, including the shell itself).

Comment: @buddy2891, ...btw, running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it found before asking here may not have fixed your bug, but it certainly would have reduced the number of comments unrelated to the question itself. (And consider me to have seconded the request for logs of your scripts being run with a `#!/bin/bash -x` shebang on each).

Comment: Why do you put the second script first and the first script second and name `bash` scripts with `.sh` extension? It's no wonder you are confused. Also, if you have made quoting improvements as suggested in the comments by multiple people, please update your question to reflect your current best effort, else everyone has to wade through all the comments. Likewise, if you tried adding `-xv` to the shebang line, please click `edit` under your question and update it with the output to try and help yourself.